# If-Else condition is not working for my test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an if-else condition in my test case. But function not going in else condition , it just look for if (condition).I am not able to figure out the problem.

**Using java with selenium webdriver**

public static void afterMenthod() throws InterruptedException {

```
    try {

        if (remoteDriver.findElementByName("Confirmation").isDisplayed()) 
        {
            if (remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").isDisplayed())
                {
                    remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").click();
                }
            else
                {
                    remoteDriver.findElementByName("Resume").click();
                    remoteDriver.findElementByName("Navigate up").click();
                    remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").click();
                }

        }

        else if (remoteDriver.findElementByName("TRY AGAIN").isDisplayed())

            {
                System.out
                        .println("There is some problem in deposit transaction");
                remoteDriver.findElementByName("Navigate up").click();
                remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").click();
                remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").click();

            }
        else if (remoteDriver.findElementByName("NEXT").isDisplayed() || remoteDriver.findElementByName("SUBMIT").isDisplayed() )
        {
            System.out.println("There is some problem in deposit transaction");
            remoteDriver.findElementByName("Navigate up").click();
            remoteDriver.findElementByName("Stop").click();
        }

        else {
            // if(remoteDriver.findElementByName("namaskaar").isDisplayed())

            System.out
                    .println("There is some problem in deposit transaction");
        }
    } finally{

    GeneralMethods.signout();
    System.out.println("Script Over");

}}
```

It just look for "confirmation" element, if it does not find that test get fails.

Comment: check if `confirmation` displayed or not

Comment: Debug your code

Comment: Did you checked if "remoteDriver.findElementByName("Confirmation")" is not null in that case it will be a null pointer will occur.

Comment: Is it going into `if` block always?

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal :: Yes it is going into "if" block always.

Comment: Well "fails" means what? What errors are you getting? I know you are getting a number of exceptions but aren't telling us.

Comment: @Arran :Error::An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.  And --> through Appium log :: [ANDROID] [debug] Finding Confirmation using NAME with the contextId:

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a different selector, try findElementById, if the element has a unique ID, otherwise use a CSS or xpath selector. Post the HTML surrounding this 'confirmation' element for more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking whether the element is displayed AND enabled

```
WebElement confirmation = remoteDriver.findElementByName("Confirmation");

if ( confirmation.isDisplayed() && confirmation.isEnabled()) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It is working for Confirmation. It works for anything which I put in first if condition. My concern is for else part. It  does not reach to else block

Comment: If condition doesn't handle Exception and in my if condition it is throwing an NoSuchElementFound Exception, so before putting if-else condition I need to check whether the element exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Write Your Else Part In catch block.

This way if an exception occurs, your else block will get executed.

It worked for me.

My Code to find a element in scroll-able screen and click it.

```
public static void scrollToBeFound(String Value) throws InterruptedException{
            try{
                driver.findElementByName(Value).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                try{
                    driver.swipe(120,420,120,750,1500);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    driver.findElementByName(Value).click();
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    driver.swipe(120,750,120,420,1500);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    driver.findElementByName(Value).click();
                }
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

"It just look for "confirmation" element, if it does not find that test get fails."  - that's because findElementByName throws an exception if element is not found. Which is why the else is not getting processed. You need to use try-catch-finally in your code. Search any forum on how to use it.

Comment: I put my code into try-finally block but still it is not routing to the else block..I have updated my code with try-finally.

Comment: You are missing the catch block. All the steps which you want to execute when there is an exception should go into the catch block.

Comment: @Nitesh When you tried with the catch block did execution go into the catch block?